# Как в YII сделать сортировку в таблице по полю "status" и при этом чтоб выполнялся поиск?

Tags: php, mysql, yii, crud

Модель Zayavki:

```
    public function search()
   {



public function search()
{


    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->select='*';  
    $criteria->condition='status=:status';
    $criteria->params=array(':status'=>"исполнено");
    $post=Zayavki::model()->find($criteria);


    $criteria->compare('id_zayavki',$this->id_zayavki);
    $criteria->compare('title_z',$this->title_z,true);
    $criteria->compare('date',$this->date,true);
    $criteria->compare('time',$this->time,true);
    $criteria->compare('dlit',$this->dlit);
    $criteria->compare('col',$this->col);
    $criteria->compare('fio',$this->fio,true);
    $criteria->compare('datesozd',$this->datesozd,true);
    $criteria->compare('timesozd',$this->timesozd,true);
    $criteria->compare('status',$this->status);
    $criteria->compare('avto',$this->avto,true);
    $criteria->compare('coment',$this->coment,true);
    $criteria->compare('district',$this->district,true);
    $criteria->compare('selo',$this->selo,true);
    $criteria->compare('adres',$this->adres,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,

                'sort' => array (
        'defaultOrder'=>array(
            'id_zayavki'=>CSort::SORT_DESC,
        )
    )
    ));
}
```

В таблице показываются строки со статусом *исполнено*. Если в поле поиска, по статусу, сделать поиск со статусом *отказано*, то записи по удовлетворяющему запросу не находятся.

Comment: а зачем тогда фильтруете по "исполнено", если надо и "отказано" показывать?

Comment: на главной странице надо чтобы показывались только те записи у которых статус "исполнено" - поэтому сортировка идет, но если нужно посмотреть записи со статусом "отказано" просто вбить в поиске и они найдутся. Проблема -  как сделать чтоб была сортировка по одному статусу и был поиск по всем возможным статусам заявки.

Comment: ну так уберите фильтрацию по "исполнено" и передавайте ее параметром

Comment: Если не трудно пример бы мне, где-куда-как

Comment: убираете `$criteria->condition='status=:status'; $criteria->params=array(':status'=>"исполнено");` а на главной передаете параметр `status` так же как при поиске его передаете

Comment: я удалил эти строчки и у меня сейчас все заявки со всеми статусами выводятся (новый, на исполнении, исполнено, отказано). В каком месте что изменить чтоб выводились записи  скажем только со статусом исполнено. Я для этого и написал сортировку

Comment: я не знаю же ваш код, поэтому не могу сказать что и где надо заменить, чтобы было так, как вы хотите. У вас же как-то поиск работает, вот так же и для главной страницы надо сделать. Представьте, что пользователь ищет записи, у которых "status" равен "исполнено", вот так и сделайте

Comment: Вообщем я с самого начала не тот вопрос задал) мне требуется на своей страницы выводить записи со статусом "новый" и "на исполнении". Сортировка это реализовала. А затем поищу-ка я записи со статусом "отказано", ввожу в поиск и ничего 0 записей, хотя они есть в бд.